# Getting the bundle identifier of an OS X application in a shell script

Tags: macos

One option would be to use AppleScript:

```
$ osascript -e 'id of app "Finder"'
com.apple.finder
```

You could also do something like this:

```
$ bundle=$(mdfind -onlyin / kMDItemKind==Application | grep -i "/Finder.app$" | head -1)
$ defaults read "$bundle/Contents/Info" CFBundleIdentifier
com.apple.finder
```

Both of these are fairly slow (about 0.05-0.2s on my Air) though. Are there any faster or less hacky options?

Comment: Using `defaults read` seems like the right way to do it (or else querying LaunchServices via Obj-C) - why do you consider 0.1s slow?

Comment: I like the `osascript` solution.  How many times a second do you need to run this though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If showing all filename extensions is enabled, kMDItemDisplayName contains .app for some applications but not others. This would also escape names that contain `'`, `"`, or `\`:

`a="Consultant's Canary"; a="${a//\'/\'}.app"; a=${a//"/\\"}; a=${a//\\/\\\\}; mdls -name kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier -raw "$(mdfind 'kMDItemContentType==com.apple.application-bundle&&kMDItemFSName=="'"$a"'"' | head -n1)"`

Another option:

`a=Finder; mdls -name kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier -raw "$(mdfind kMDItemContentType==com.apple.application-bundle | sed -E $'s|(.*/)(.*)|\\1\t\\2|' | grep -F $'\t'"$a".app -m1 | tr -d '\t')"`

A single osascript command might also be faster:

```
osascript -e 'on run args
set output to {}
repeat with a in args
set end of output to id of app a
end
set text item delimiters to linefeed
output as text
end' Finder 'AppleScript Editor'
```

Answer (score 52):

How about reading the bundle identifier from the application's Info.plist file directly using PlistBuddy (8):

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print CFBundleIdentifier' /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

Comment: Can I get the bundle identifier for a deleted app?

Comment: +1 Worked for AnyDesk.

Comment: `defaults read /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Info.plist CFBundleIdentifier` does the same trick

Answer (score 37):

`mdls -name kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier -r SomeApp.app`

Answer (score 20):

Use `lsappinfo`

```
CC@~ $ lsappinfo info -only bundleid Finder
"CFBundleIdentifier"="com.apple.finder"
```

To get only the bundleid value, add `| cut -d '"' -f4` to that command

```
CC@~ $ lsappinfo info -only bundleid Finder | cut -d '"' -f4
com.apple.finder
```

You don't have to handle your code with the path of that application, even the path changes.

As long as the application is started, you got an value.

Though it is not as fast as @surry's answer, but it's fast enough.

Comment: I’m not the downvoter, but this does not work reliably for me (while the others methods do). It’s working with some apps but not all.

Comment: @user137369 Could you please tell me what's that app? BTW, the app has to be launched to use `lsappinfo`

Comment: `lsappinfo` only works on currently-running apps.

Comment: `lsappinfo` outputs only a blank line for my currently-running apps.

Answer (score 1):

Values of `kMDItemKind` depend on the current localization.

How about this?

```
mdls -name kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier \
     -raw "$(mdfind "(kMDItemContentTypeTree=com.apple.application) && (kMDItemDisplayName == 'photoshop*'cdw)" | head -1)"
```